# PostgreSQL ODBC “Data source name not found, and no default driver specified”

Tags: postgresql, odbc, hana, greenplum

I am trying to connect my HANA Server (SLES) with a Greenplum cluster. In my HANA server I have installed the last version of PostgreSQL and PostgreSQL ODBC. In "`/usr/local/lib/`" path I have the following files:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1056 May  8 14:31 psqlodbca.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1382864 May  8 14:31 psqlodbca.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1056 May  8 14:31 psqlodbcw.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1494311 May  8 14:31 psqlodbcw.so
```

Therefore I have installed PostgreSQL ODBC correctly.

In `/etc/odbc.ini` I have the following configuration:

```
[psqlodbc_test_dsn]
Description             = psqlodbc regression test DSN
Driver          = PostgreSQL Unicode
Trace           = Yes
TraceFile               =
Database                = contrib_regression
Servername              = mdw.aws
Username                = root
Password                =
Port                    = 5432
ReadOnly                = No
RowVersioning           = No
ShowSystemTables                = No
ShowOidColumn           = No
FakeOidIndex            = No
ConnSettings            = set lc_messages='C'
```

And in `/etc/odbcinst.ini` I have the following configuration:

```
[PostgreSQL Unicode]
Description     = PostgreSQL ODBC driver (Unicode version), for regression tests
Driver          = ../.libs/psqlodbcw.so
Debug           = 0
CommLog         = 0
```

When in `/etc/odbc.ini` I change `Driver = /usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.so` and I try to run "`isql -v psqlodbc_test_dsn`" the following error appears:

> [01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.so' : file not found
>
> [ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect

But when in `/etc/odbc.ini` I change `Driver = PostgreSQL Unicode` and I try to run "`isql -v psqlodbc_test_dsn`" the following error appears:

> [IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
>
> [ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect

What could be the error? Thanks for the support!

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. Are you using HANA, Greenplum or Postgres?

Comment: I am using a HANA Server (with SLES) where i have installed postgresSQL ODBC to connect with a master greenplum machine (with centos) where i have installed greenplum.

Comment: If you run `ldd /usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.so` - are there any unmet dependencies?

Comment: If I run "ldd /usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.so", the following lines appears: 
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff4333f000)
libpq.so.5 => not found
libodbcinst.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libodbcinst.so.2 (0x00007fc2cb975000)
libltdl.so.7 => /usr/lib64/libltdl.so.7 (0x00007fc2cb76b000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fc2cb567000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc2cb349000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc2cafd0000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc2cbe29000)

Comment: I have execute the command "ln -s /usr/local/pgsql/lib/libpq.so.5 /usr/lib64/libpq.so.5" because I saw the "libpq.so.5" had no dependencies, and I have been able to fix it. Now, when I execute "isql -v psqlodbc_test_dsn", an error changed by the following: "[08001][unixODBC]could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect" What could be the error? Thanks for the support!